# Is there a way to add query parameter to every request with Retrofit 2?

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I need to add a query parameter to every request made by Retrofit 2.0.0-beta2 library. I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17580223/) for Retrofit 1.9, but how to add `RequestInterceptor` in newest library version?

My interface:

```
@GET("user/{id}")
Call<User> getUser(@Path("id")long id);

@GET("users/")
Call<List<User>> getUser();
```

Client:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .client(CLIENT)  // custom OkHTTP Client
                    .build();
service = retrofit.create(userService.class);
```

Comment: If you managed to add a query parameter in the interceptor, could you add the code in your question or in a response of your own question?

Answer (score 158, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, here is the full code you need to add a parameter to every Retrofit 2.x request using a OkHttp-Interceptor:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

client.interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();
        HttpUrl url = request.url().newBuilder().addQueryParameter("name","value").build();
        request = request.newBuilder().url(url).build();
        return chain.proceed(request);
    }
});

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("...")
        .client(client)
        .build();
```

Comment: `httpUrl()` method in the `Request` object was changed to `url()` in the latest version of the OkHttp

Comment: `interceptors()` returns immutable `List` in `3.2.0`. Use `addInterceptor()` in `OkHttpClient.Builder` instead.

Comment: The added parameter will be set in GET, it can be an issue if you need to use another request type.

Answer (score 13):

now the Retrofit has release 2.0.0 and this is my solution:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {

                String uid = "0";
                long timestamp = (int) (Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() / 1000);
                String signature = MD5Util.crypt(timestamp + "" + uid + MD5_SIGN);
                String base64encode = signature + ":" + timestamp + ":" + uid;
                base64encode = Base64.encodeToString(base64encode.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP | Base64.URL_SAFE);

                Request request = chain.request();
                HttpUrl url = request.url()
                        .newBuilder()
                        .addQueryParameter("pageSize", "2")
                        .addQueryParameter("method", "getAliasList")
                        .build();

                request = request
                        .newBuilder()
                        .addHeader("Authorization", "zui " + base64encode)
                        .addHeader("from_client", "ZuiDeer")
                        .url(url)
                        .build();

                Response response = chain.proceed(request);
                return response;
            }
        }).build();


Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(ApiConstants.API_BASE_URL)
        .client(client)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
        .build();

mRestfulService = retrofit.create(RestfulService.class);
```

Answer (score 8):

In kotlin, add the following interceptor to the OkHttpClient you set in Retrofit builder :

```
Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("...")
    .client(
        OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor { chain ->
                val url = chain
                    .request()
                    .url()
                    .newBuilder()
                    .addQueryParameter("key", "value")
                    .build()
                chain.proceed(chain.request().newBuilder().url(url).build())
            }
            .build()
    )
    .build()
    .create(FooService::class.java)
```

And, of course, extracting the OkHttpClient building into a val or an injection dependency would make it even more modular and lisible.

Answer (score 6):

In `3.2.0` and higher you should use `addInterceptor()` in `OkHttpClient.Builder` instead.

For example, with [`Retrolambda`](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/me.tatarka.retrolambda):

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        .setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC);

Interceptor clientInterceptor = chain -> {
    Request request = chain.request();
    HttpUrl url = request.url().newBuilder().addQueryParameter("name", "value").build();
    request = request.newBuilder().url(url).build();
    return chain.proceed(request);
};

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addNetworkInterceptor(clientInterceptor)
        .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
        .build();

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .client(client)
        .build();
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to switch to an `Interceptor` from `OkHttp`. Create an `OkHttpClient`, add the `Interceptor` to it an pass that client in the Retrofit `Builder`.

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
client.interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        ...
    }
});

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("...")
        .client(client)
        .build();
```

You can then adjust the request to your needs using `chain.request().newBuilder()`. See the [documentation](https://square.github.io/okhttp/javadoc/com/squareup/okhttp/Interceptor.Chain.html) for details.

Comment: It absolutely doesn't explain how to add a Query Parameter. It just explains how to intercept, but I only found a way to add headers, and the OP and me want to add a query parameter

Comment: You can modify the request chain to your needs, see the OkHttp documentation for details. (example: chain.proceed(chain.request().newBuilder().url(chain.request().httpUrl().newBuilder().addQueryParameter("name", "value").build()).build());
// http://square.github.io/okhttp/javadoc/com/squareup/okhttp/HttpUrl.Builder.html#addQueryParameter-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)

Comment: You're right. As the API changed, it was harder to find how to add the query parameters, so your solution didn't helped me, until I found httpurl also had a newBuilder method. I think you should add it to your question

Answer (score 2):

A lot of these answers are similar, but an issue I came accross is the chaining of functions inside the `Interceptor` which led it to fail for me.  Changes [cannot be made directly to a url](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-add-query-parameters-to-every-request) according to the linked video.  Rather, a copy of the url must be made and then reassigned back to the original url as shown below:

{

```
public method(){
    final String api_key = "key";

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                          .addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                              @Override
                              public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                                    Request original = chain.request();
                                    HttpUrl httpUrl = original.url();

                                    HttpUrl newHttpUrl = httpUrl
                                                        .newBuilder()
                                                        .addQueryParameter("api_key", api_key)
                                                        .build();

                                    Request.Builder requestBuilder = original
                                                                 .newBuilder()
                                                             .url(newHttpUrl);

                                    Request request = requestBuilder
                                                      .build();
                                    return chain.proceed(request);
                              }
                          }).build();


    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://base.url.ext/")
            .client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
}
```

While the functions called are identical to the first answer, this answer partitions the function calls out.  Namely, the original url as well as the new url are stored in separate local variables. This prevents overwriting the original url until you want the `OkHttpClient` to do so.

Answer (score 2):

For a cleaner code approach have a separate class for the interceptor chain like this:

```java
    public class LanguageInterceptor implements Interceptor {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            HttpUrl url = chain.request()
                    .url()
                    .newBuilder()
                    .addQueryParameter("name","value")
                    .build();

            Request request = chain.request()
                    .newBuilder()
                    .url(url)
                    .build();
            Response response = chain.proceed(request);
            return response;
        }
    }
```

Then in the class where you defined your retrofit instance you add the instance object to it with `.addInterceptor(new LanguageInterceptor())` like this:

```java
public static Retrofit getClient() {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .addInterceptor(new LanguageInterceptor())
                .addInterceptor(interceptor)
                .build();

        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .client(client)
                    .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
            Log.e(TAG, "getClient: base url " + retrofit.baseUrl());
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
```

Comment: Just awesome! Exactly what I needed, I had to support many languages (in a biggg project)  and this is the best solution :)