# How do you add constant Body fields in retroift POST request?

Tags: android, http-post, retrofit2, http-post-vars

You can add static headers to retrofit requests using @Headers({}), and specific body fields using @field in the method arguments. But I want to submit constant (non-json) name-value parameters in the body of a post request. The retrofit [documentation](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) does not mention it. I shouldn't have to use an interceptor to do this either. Is [@FieldMap](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-send-data-form-urlencoded-using-fieldmap) in the method parameters my only option ? Or is there an annotation that will permit constant Fieldmap similar to @Headers ?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/33667739/1025379

Comment: thanks for the response, but i need to do it without interceptors.. (it was in the original question)

Comment: how about this? @POST("users/new?sort=desc")

Answer (score 1):

You can use okHttp's [RequestBody](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/7135628c645892faf1a48a8cff464e0ed4ad88cb/okhttp/src/main/java/okhttp3/RequestBody.java) as your parameter

```
@POST("path")
Call<ResponseBody> postWithPlainText(@Body RequestBody requestBody);
```

And then use it like this

```
String plainText = "Your constant here";  
RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), plainText);

Call<ResponseBody> call = service.postWithPlainText(requestBody); 
Response<ResponseBody> response = call.execute();
```

Comment: So you cannot setup a static body in a post request using annotations like \\@Headers. It seems that I have to submit the body via the method parameters using \\@Body ?

Comment: @giulio Yes I don't think you can do that with just adding an annotation.